# How do I restore the previous behavior when double-clicking on a floating tool windows in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, multiple-monitors

With Visual Stuido 2010's multi-monitor support, I like the support for code windows, but the support for tool windows is seriously lacking. For instance, I want to restore the behavior when double-clicking on a floating tool windows to "docked", not "maximize".

*How do I restore the previous behavior when double-clicking on a floating tool windows in Visual Studio 2010?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key when double-clicking on the tool window title bar.  That should restore it instead of maximizing it.

Comment: I tried all the shift keys before and it didn't work. I just tried now and it works. Go figure. Thank you very much.